# Is it possible to detect the entire face region (only) in IOS?

Tags: ios5, quartz-graphics, core-image, face-recognition, quartz-core

I need to detect the full face region in my app...
Is it possible to detect that region ?

Currently i was using the **CIDector** to get the face features...
CIDector detects only nose,left and right eye...

how do i detect the entire full face(not as square marked face entire space. I attached the image below exactly what is the need) from the source image...?

any idea or solution for this problem is highly appreciated...

Thanks in advance....

Regards,

Spynet

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, if it is possible to do it using **CIDetector**. I would recommend you more sofisticated solution like **OpenCV**. Take a look here: http://www.eosgarden.com/en/opensource/opencv-ios/overview/

and to the **OpenCV documentation**:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/

Hope it helps. It is ore complicated way but you can handle it.

Comment: Thanks still i am having the issue now i am changing the image pixel by pixel.... please see the below link...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516691/how-to-detect-the-skin-color-of-face-from-the-source-image-in-ios-5