# Teeth whitening iOS

Tags: ios, face-detection

I want to detect the teeth from an image and want to whiten them with slider.

I found the following code for mouth detection. But how should I detect the exact  teeth location so that I could whiten them. Is there any third party for this?

```
// draw a CI image with the previously loaded face detection picture
    CIImage* image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:imageView.image.CGImage];

    // create a face detector - since speed is not an issue now we'll use a high accuracy detector
    CIDetector* detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace 
                                              context:nil options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh forKey:CIDetectorAccuracy]];

    // create an array containing all the detected faces from the detector
    NSArray* features = [detector featuresInImage:image];

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, -imageView.bounds.size.height);


    for(CIFaceFeature* faceFeature in features)
    {
        // Get the face rect: Translate CoreImage coordinates to UIKit coordinates
        const CGRect faceRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(faceFeature.bounds, transform);

        // create a UIView using the bounds of the face
        UIView* faceView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:faceRect];
        faceView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
        faceView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];

        // get the width of the face
        CGFloat faceWidth = faceFeature.bounds.size.width;

        // add the new view to create a box around the face
        [imageView addSubview:faceView];

        if(faceFeature.hasMouthPosition)
        {
            // Get the mouth position translated to imageView UIKit coordinates
            const CGPoint mouthPos = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(faceFeature.mouthPosition, transform);

            // Create an UIView to represent the mouth, its size depend on the width of the face.

            UIView* mouth = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(mouthPos.x - faceWidth*MOUTH_SIZE_RATE*0.5,
                                                                     mouthPos.y - faceWidth*MOUTH_SIZE_RATE*0.5,
                                                                     faceWidth*MOUTH_SIZE_RATE,
                                                                     faceWidth*MOUTH_SIZE_RATE)];

            // make the mouth look nice and add it to the view
            mouth.backgroundColor = [[UIColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3];
            //mouth.layer.cornerRadius = faceWidth*MOUTH_SIZE_RATE*0.5;
            [imageView addSubview:mouth];

             NSLog(@"Mouth %g %g", faceFeature.mouthPosition.x, faceFeature.mouthPosition.y);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show me what image your getting? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516691/how-to-detect-the-skin-color-of-face-from-the-source-image-in-ios-5

Comment: Please check it in this link :https://github.com/nacho4d/FaceDetectionExample2

Comment: please see the limitations https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_detect_faces/ci_detect_faces.html

Comment: I have seen many apps with the same functionality.

Comment: please mention anyone app so that i can understand what you want achieve?

Comment: App name is whitening Simulator. I want to achieve just the automatic part of this app in my app..

Comment: hi @SwatiGupta  , do you have any solution for this issue? Can you share me, please!

Comment: @swati Gupta did you got any solution? Please share me. I want to do same.

Comment: Is there any workaround so far?

Comment: @SwatiGupta Is there any update on this ? Want to achieve same things. Any help on this will be much appreciate.